# How many self-injective quiver algebras are there?

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory

Given a fixed finite quiver $Q$ over a field $K$ (possibly finite), is there a quick way to determine how many self-injective quiver algebras $KQ/I$ (with admissible ideal) of Loewy length at most $m \geq 2$ exist up to isomorphism ($Q$ and $m$ are fixed)?

Recall that a quiver algebra being self-injective is a purely combinatorial condition—self-injectivity holds iff there exists a permutation $\pi$ such that ${\mathrm {soc}}(S_{\pi(i)})={\mathrm {top}}(P(S_i))$, where $S_j$ denotes a simple module and $P(S)$ the projective cover.

The answer is infinite if the field is the complex numbers and $m=3$ when $Q$ consists of one point and two loops.

So in general there might be infinitely many (except when the field is finite) and the problem might be too complicated. If this is the case, I'm also interested in special cases; for example, if $Q$ is the quiver of a preprojective algebra of type A or D.

As a concrete example (a quiver of a preprojective algebra of type A), let $a_{n,m}$ be the number of self-injective quiver algebras up to isomorphism with Loewy length at most $m \geq 2$ and the underlying quiver $Q$ having $n$ points and one arrow from $i$ to $i+1$ and one from $i+1$ to $i$ for $i=1,2,...,n-1$. What is $a_{n,m}$? As an example, $a_{2,m}=1$. It might be that the answer in this case is independent of the field; this occurs if $Q$ is an oriented cycle. Are there other cases?